# Obter todas as informações do arquivo que veio do input file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sei que é possível no PHP, receber um determinado arquivo e obter todas as informações do mesmo, como extensão, tamanho, data, entre outros.

Gostaria de saber como é possível obter essas informações com javascript.

O usuário precisa selecionar uma imagem, e gostaria de obter a extensão da imagem, o tamanho e altura.

Comment: O que esteve tentando?

Comment: Bom consegui pouca conquista em relação a essa dúvida. A única coisa que consegui até agora é detectar se o input sofreu algum upload de arquivo ou não.

Comment: Continuei com algumas informações que vi na internet, mas não obtive resultado. var arq = this.files[0];
   alert(arq.name);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O HTML5 fornece um formato padrão de interação com arquivos locais por meio da especificação da [API de arquivos](https://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/) (link em inglês). Como exemplo de seus recursos, a API de arquivos pode ser utilizada para criar uma visualização em miniatura das imagens ao serem enviadas para o servidor ou permitir que o aplicativo salve uma referência do arquivo quando o usuário estiver off-line. Além disso, você pode utilizar a lógica do lado do cliente para confirmar se o mimetype de um upload corresponde a sua extensão de arquivo ou restringir o tamanho de um upload.

A especificação fornece várias interfaces para acessar arquivos de um sistema de arquivos "local":

- Arquivo - um arquivo individual; Fornece informações legítimas, como nome, tamanho do arquivo, tipo de mime e uma referência ao identificador do arquivo.
- FileList - uma seqüência semelhante a uma matriz de objetos File. (Pense  ou arrastando um diretório de arquivos da área de trabalho).
- Blob - Permite cortar um arquivo em intervalos de bytes.

A forma mais direta de carregar um arquivo é utilizar o elemento padrão . O JavaScript retorna a lista de objetos File selecionados como uma FileList. Este exemplo usa o atributo "multiple" para permitir a seleção de diversos arquivos de uma única vez:

```js
// Verifica se as APIs de arquivo são suportadas pelo navegador.
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
  // Todas as APIs são suportadas!
} else {
  alert('A APIs de arquivos não é totalmente suportada neste navegador.');
}


function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // Objeto FileList guarda todos os arquivos.
  var output = [];
  //Intera sobre os arquivos e lista esses objetos no output.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
//        console.log('Objeto do arquivo', f);
    // Informação adicional se for imagem:
    if (f.type.match('image.*')) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      //A leitura do arquivo é assíncrona 
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
//              console.log('Img info', e, theFile);
          // Gera a miniatura:
          var img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = e.target.result;
          img.title = escape(theFile.name);

          var span = document.createElement('span');
          //Obtém o tamanho:
          //Só é possível obter o tamanho do arquivo após o carregamento dele na miniatura, como o src é um base64 gerado à partir do arquivo local não terá custo de carregamento através da rede.
          img.onload = function(){
            var i = document.createElement('i');
          i.innerHTML = "<br>Tamanho Miniatura: " + img.width + "px Largura - " + img.height + "px Altura <br> Tamanho original:"+ img.naturalWidth+ "px Largura - " + img.naturalWidth+ "px Altura";
          span.appendChild(i);

          //Esse método retorna o tamanho calculado: Resultado esperado ((proporcional)x75) 

          //var width = img.clientWidth;
          //var height = img.clientHeight;
          }
          
          span.appendChild(img);
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }

    output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
      f.size, ' bytes,  última modificação: ',
      f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
      '</li>');
  }
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
img {
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>
```

Fonte: https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 2):

Com o script abaixo você conseguirá obter o nome, extensão, tamanho, altura e largura da imagem enviada pelo usuário:

```js
$('#imagem').change(function() {
  var img = document.getElementById('imagem');
  //Obter o nome da imagem
  var nome = this.files[0].name;
  //Obter a extensão
  var extensao = nome.replace(/^.*\./, '');

  //Calcular o tamanho do arquivo  
  var tamanho = ($("#imagem")[0].files[0].size / 1024);
  if (tamanho / 1024 > 1) {
    if (((tamanho / 1024) / 1024) > 1) {
      tamanho = (Math.round(((tamanho / 1024) / 1024) * 100) / 100);
      tamanho = tamanho + "Gb";
    } 
    else {
      tamanho = (Math.round((tamanho / 1024) * 100) / 100)
      tamanho = tamanho + "Mb";
    }
  } 
  else {
    tamanho = (Math.round(tamanho * 100) / 100)
    tamanho = tamanho + "kb";
  }
  //Obter largura e altura da imagem
  var altura = img.clientHeight;
  var largura = img.clientWidth;

  alert('Nome: ' + nome + "\nExtensão: " + extensao + '\nTamanho: ' + tamanho + "\nAltura: " + altura + "px" + "\nLargura: " + largura + "px");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" name="imagem" id="imagem" accept="image/*">
```